# PHP Date String Compression

Tags: php, date

I have an interesting question.

In a table, I have a field which is in the following format

YYMMDD001 (001 is an incremental up to 999)

This data is used to be exported into an accounting software which has the same field with a limit of 9 numeric characters.

The Problem is that we need more than 999 values for a particular day.

So far with php we have like

```
$unique = date("Y-m-d").$counter; // $counter is sprintf'd to have leading zeros
```

And the best solution we have so far is a 5 digit date using Year and day number so the incremental part is expanded to 9999.

Anyone can proposed something which is less than 5 digit? (For the date part)

PS: We cannot use hex, we are tied to just basic numerical representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "number of days since date X".

Choose, say Jan 1st, 1970 or something you like more for the start point and you'll end up with more than 270 years encoded in 5 digits.

For 4 digits it's 27 years, which I'm sure is still enough for this task (if you start counting from these days or so).

Comment: I like... I will wait for a few minutes more and then choose an answer :)

Comment: "For 4 digits it's 27 years, which I'm sure is still enough for this task (if you start counting from these days or so)."

This is what did the trick, to avoid conflicts we opted to use it as follows...

<daysSinceToday>4<XXXX>

The 4 is used to avoid conflicts with past data, since 4 can never appear in the first digit of a day 2 digit value (sicne no month have more than 31 days)

Thanks!